# OpenEdge ABL automatically close a yes/no message after a certon amount of time has pasted

Tags: message, openedge

Right now I have:
message "Hello World" view-as alert-box warning buttons yes-no update lVariable.

how can I automatically click the no after 14 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do this "another way":

```
DEFINE FRAME f-message
      "This is your message"
      WITH CENTERED
      OVERLAY
      .


DO ON ENDKEY UNDO, LEAVE:

VIEW FRAME f-message.

PAUSE 14 NO-MESSAGE.

HIDE FRAME f-message.

END.
```

Answer (score 0):

In ChUi, you can't.

(and this is some more characters so I make the 30 char minimum for an answer.)

Comment: Sorry what is ChuI. Not sure if I have it.

Comment: ChUI = Character User Interface. It's all text.

Comment: I'm using GUI mode. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I don't think so for that statement. You'll need to use something else in conjunction with something like "pstimer".

Why not just throw up a message box in a frame, the PAUSE 14 NO-MESSAGE, and then move on?

Comment: is there something else i can use other then message that gives the same effect but gives me more control?

Comment: See the next answer, and please upvote them since they are helping you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on version 10.2b+ you might be able to use the STOP-AFTER clause on a do/for/repeat block to control this.

Not sure as I don't have that version myself to try.

BTW. Always put your version on a question as it can make a difference to the options available.

Comment: Ya i have version 10.2b. STOP-AFTER is a good idea but it doesn't close the message box.

Comment: do you know any way to close the message box?

Comment: You marked a suggestion that doesn't work as the "best answer"?  Tim's answer below (the one with "PAUSE 14" in it) actually works...